# ViewPager - Change sizes dynamically using PageTransformer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I'm trying to make the screen look like this:

`|view 1|   view 2   |view 3| 
|          screen          |`

View 2 is the current view of the `ViewPager`, 2 times the width of 2 other views, and a bit higher than those 2 views. View 1 and View 3 are full views like View 2, not partial views. Using `PageTransformer`, I've been able to make the current view achieved the height wanted plus very nice subtle animation, but I haven't been able to make it wider.

So how can I make View 2 wider using `PageTransformer`? Thanks for any answer/comments!

Comment: whats width and height value for `ViewPager`

Comment: @Jayanth well, I set `layout_marginTop` to 250dp and `setPadding(screenWidth / 4, 0, screenWidth / 2, 0)` for `ViewPager`